# How to find/replace text only in Excel (or Google Sheets), but keep integers

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have an Excel spreadsheet (Mac OS) with approximately 500 rows and 50+ columns. In all 500 rows, but only half of the columns, are URLs that I am looking to change in bulk.

The domain name and first two category names (paths) are the same. The third path is different but will always contain two letters only. And the final/last text path before the numbers/integers is different.

I am looking to remove the entire URL, including the .html extension, but keep the unique numbers/integers.

```
https://www.website.com/category/product/oh/brody/3302.html
https://www.website.com/category/product/in/greene/6648.html
https://www.website.com/category/product/ca/ronald/9858.html
https://www.website.com/category/product/nj/brick/2464.html
https://www.website.com/category/product/tx/allen/1104.html`
```

- **Desired result**

```
    3302
    6648
    9858
    2462
    1104
```

I am open to doing this in Excel or Google Sheets, as well as multiple steps to accomplish this task

- Find "https://www.website.com/category/product" and replace with nothing
- Find ".html" and replace with nothing
- This still leaves thousands of almost-complete results:

```
    /oh/brody/3302
    /in/greene/6648
    /ca/ronald/9858
    /nj/brick/2464
    /tx/allen/1104
```

I want to be left with only this:

```
    3302
    6648
    9858
    2462
    1104
```

Answer (score 2):

Using "=Right, 9" function would return the final 9 characters from the end of the string of text. IE "3302.html" then you could use your replace function as you did previously to remove the suffix.

** Edit - incorrect function suggested, forgot left from right
[image]

Comment: Or nest the `LEFT()`: `=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,9),5)`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+")*1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets:

1. Highlight desired cells to change
2. Find https://www.website.com/category/product and replace empty
3. Find .html and replace empty
4. Find [^0-9.] and replace empty and tick 'Search using regular expression[image]'